# Java voice chat over UDP - how do I get the port?

Tags: java, audio, udp, voice, datagram

Currently I have a server and a client. The client joins a voice chat room and any sound produced from the mic is sent to the server. Once the server receives it, it sends it out to all clients connected. That is where I run into my issue:

For some reason this code is not playing the audio back. Eventually I want it to only play other clients audio, but for now I'm just trying to make it play all audio back and can't seem do that.

Below is my code:

```
public class VoiceReceiveThread extends Thread{
    public DatagramSocket din;
    public SourceDataLine audio_out;
    public DatagramSocket dout;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while (MainWindow.isVConnected) {            
            try {
                din.receive(incoming);
                buffer = incoming.getData();
                audio_out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        audio_out.close();
        audio_out.drain();
    }
}
```

When I set `din` to `new DatagramSocket(null);` the code runs but does not give me any feedback. Do I need to be running on a specific port? What am I doing?

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT: **Here is my server, its mostly the same thing. If I listen to the audio from the server it works fine, its only when I try to send it back from the server to the client where is doesn't receive the packets. I've gone through my code again and it seems to be that the packets aren't being received on the clients end.

```
public class VoiceTransferThread extends Thread{
    public DatagramSocket din;
    public SourceDataLine audio_out;
    public Socket s;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    public DatagramSocket dout;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;
        DatagramPacket incoming  = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            dout = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(s.getInetAddress() + " " + s.getPort());
        while (RSVCServer.isVConnected) {            
            try {
                din.receive(incoming);
                buffer = incoming.getData();
                //audio_out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, s.getInetAddress(), s.getPort());
                dout.send(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        audio_out.close();
        audio_out.drain();
        System.out.println("stop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions? You need to decide on a port to use and that port must be reachable.

Comment: No exceptions seems to pause at `din.receive`, its likely waiting for input.

Comment: Then it never gets a packet. Did you send a udp packet to the correct port? Are you sure it's getting through your firewall/router?

Comment: @SpiderPig How would I go about checking my firewall/router? I fairly sure it is getting sent to the correct IP/port.

Comment: Write a very simple server and client. Each only a few lines long. All those two test programs will do is send/receive a single udp package. Try it out locally i.e. run both programs on the same machine and next run them on two different machines and see if the package arrives.